# Exact Filtering an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need help on filtering an already filtered list.

Scenario is I have a list (`li` item with various classes) of products that is being filtered by an ID and that ID is being pushed into an array. E.g.

```
var $filtersSelected = [];
```

Using this code, I can successfully filter the list.

```
var $productItems = $('ul').find('li');
$.each($productItems, function() {

var $self = $(this),
    // Store classes of each product <li> item
    $classes = $self.attr('class').split(/\s+/),
    $match = false; 

// Check if any classes of each <li> matches those in '$filtersSelected' array
$.each($classes, function(i, c) {
    if ($.inArray(c, $filtersSelected) > -1) {
        $match = true;
    }
    return $classes;
});

// Do something
if ($match) {
    $self.show();
} else {
    $self.hide();
}
});
```

Every time I click a new filter ID, the array gets appended and any item whose classes matches those n the array gets shown. However, what I need is to be able to iterate through the already filtered items.

If I already have this items... `$filtersSelected = ["blue"]`

```
["blue", "circle", "number"]
["blue", "square", "number"]
["blue", "triangle", "letter"]
```

and click on "number".  `$filtersSelected = ["blue", "number"]` I only need these items to show until it gets the exact match.

```
["blue", "circle", "number"]
["blue", "square", "number"]
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Here's a snippet of code and how it currently works. http://jsfiddle.net/athanph/ebLyV/24/

You'll see that I got 3 sets of filter. What I want is to filter exact items based on the filters chosen. If I click "Blue" all blue items will be shown, if I click "Circle" as my second filter, I only want to show blue and circle items, and so on...

Comment: All those `$` in front of variables, do you by chance come from a PHP background?

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle? I'm not clear on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @tymeJV it is a good practice to prefix jQuery type objects with $ to quickly know if they are jQuery or native DOM objects. I don't understand why he's doing this on all variables though.

Comment: @Virus721 -- Yup, the all variables thing was getting to me :)

Comment: Do you know that you can hide or show based on classes, without having to iterate so many times and without writing so much code?

Comment: No PHP background. It's just a practice I picked up. @MaxLeske just added a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
$('ul').find('li').filter(function(){
    return this.className.indexOf($filtersSelected) > -1;
}).hide();
```

The other elements I suppose are already visible (*i.e show()*).

In above I am using some javascript code because I am not that much good with jquery. In short, I used what I know :).

Comment: Hi thanks. This hides the matched element. I setup a jsfiddle above to show my current structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, this is the code:

```
$(function () {
    var filtersSelected = [];
    $('#btAddToFilter').click(function () {
        var x = '.' + $('#txtAddToFilter').val();
        if ($.inArray(x, filtersSelected) < 0) {
            filtersSelected.push(x);
        }
        $('#ulProductItems').find('li').hide();
        $(filtersSelected.join(', ')).show()
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csicky/NKFTL/